# Cordova File Transfer with error 1

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

I tried download a image to my devide using Cordova File Transfer plugin, but i get error code 1 everytime.

This is my code:

```
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var fileOrigin = encodeURI('http://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png');
    //var fileTarget = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + ' image.png'; // Don't work
    var fileTarget = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/image.png'; // Success, but i don't find the image
    //var fileTarget = 'cdvfile://android_asset/image.png'; // Don't work
    //var fileTarget = FileEntry.toURL() + 'image.png'; // Don't work and don't create any alert
    //var fileTarget = DirectoryEntry.toURL() + 'image.png'; // Don't work and don't create alert

    fileTransfer.download(
        fileOrigin,
        fileTarget,
        function(entry){
            alert('SUCESS!');
        }, function(error){
            alert('ERROR: ' + error.code);
            alert('Target: ' + error.target);
        }
    );
    alert('Teste');
```

When i try do a fileTarget with .toURL(), all the download script don't run, and no one alert is created.

When i try do a fileTarget with "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/image.png", i receive the Success message, but don't find the image file in my device.

Where is my error?
How i can save my file in a specific folder, like DCIM/MyApp?

Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fileTarget = 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/';
```

Your `fileTarget` must be a path on the device.